# JavaScript style for optional callbacks

Tags: javascript, coding-style, callback

I have some functions which occasionally (not always) will receive a callback and run it. Is checking if the callback is defined/function a good style or is there a better way?

Example:

```
function save (callback){
   .....do stuff......
   if(typeof callback !== 'undefined'){
     callback();
   };
};
```

Comment: in modern browsers you could just use `typeof callback !== undefined` so leave out the `'`

Comment: and if you simply call `save()`? Won't that give an error or linting warning because an argument is missing? Or it's perfectly ok and callback is simply `undefined` ?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I personally prefer

`typeof callback === 'function' && callback();`

The `typeof` command is dodgy however and should only be used for `"undefined"` and `"function"`

The problems with the `typeof !== undefined` is that the user might pass in a value that is defined and *not a function*

Comment: `typeof` isn't dodgy. It's vague at times, but I wouldn't call it dodgy. Agreed, though, that if you're going to call the callback as a function, it's best to check that it's actually a function and not, you know, a number. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder dodgy might be the wrong word, it's well defined but useless due to boxing and returning `"object"` 95% of the time.

Comment: `typeof` doesn't cause boxing. `typeof "foo"` is `"string"`, not `"object"`. It's actually the only real way you can tell whether you're dealing with a string primitive or `String` object. (Perhaps you're thinking of `Object.prototype.toString`, which is [very handy](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html), but does cause boxing.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You have a point, I don't know what the value is of comparing string primitives and boxed String objects. Also I agree `.toString` is lovely for finding the `[[Class]]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you mentioned its the only way you can tell whether something is primitive or an Object. [This is a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793228/does-a-matter-whether-a-value-is-primitive-or-boxed). Maybe you want to comment.

Comment: I think checking for function is unnecessary. It is good style to force errors, that way the implementor is not misguided into thinking his callback was infact accepted.

Answer (score 55):

You can also do:

```
var noop = function(){}; // do nothing.

function save (callback){
   callback = callback || noop;
   .....do stuff......
};
```

It's specially useful if you happen to use the `callback` in a few places.

Additionally if you are using `jQuery`, you already have a function like that, it's called [$.noop](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/)

Comment: but this doesn't address the type issue isn't it?
what if I pass an array? or a String?

Comment: Simplify to `callback = callback || function(){};`

Comment: You can also make an argument optional by giving it a default value in the declaration: `function save (callback=noop) { ...`

Comment: If the User provides something that is not a function, then you can allow it to crash as it is a violation of the contract. No need to be handling every possible scenario.

Comment: More on `noop` if someone is interested https://stackoverflow.com/a/39373292

Answer (score 46):

Simply do

```
if (callback) callback();
```

I prefer to call the callback if supplied, no matter what type it is. Don't let it fail silently, so the implementor knows he passed in an incorrect argument and can fix it.

Answer (score 26):

### ECMAScript 6

```
// @param callback Default value is a noop fn.
const save = (callback = () => {}) => {
   callback(); // Executes callback when specified otherwise does nothing
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than make the callback optional, just assign a default and call it no matter what

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const save (..., callback = identity) {
  // ...
  return callback (...)
}
```

When used

```
save (...)              // callback has no effect
save (..., console.log) // console.log is used as callback
```

Such a style is called [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Here's a real example, `combinations`, that generates all possible combinations of an Array input

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const None =
  Symbol ()

const combinations = ([ x = None, ...rest ], callback = identity) =>
  x === None
    ? callback ([[]])
    : combinations
        ( rest
        , combs =>
            callback (combs .concat (combs .map (c => [ x, ...c ])))
        )

console.log (combinations (['A', 'B', 'C']))
// [ []
// , [ 'C' ]
// , [ 'B' ]
// , [ 'B', 'C' ]
// , [ 'A' ]
// , [ 'A', 'C' ]
// , [ 'A', 'B' ]
// , [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
// ]
```

Because `combinations` is defined in continuation-passing style, the above call is effectively the same

```
combinations (['A', 'B', 'C'], console.log)
// [ []
// , [ 'C' ]
// , [ 'B' ]
// , [ 'B', 'C' ]
// , [ 'A' ]
// , [ 'A', 'C' ]
// , [ 'A', 'B' ]
// , [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
// ]
```

We can also pass a custom continuation that does something else with the result

```
console.log (combinations (['A', 'B', 'C'], combs => combs.length))
// 8
// (8 total combinations)
```

Continuation-passing style can be used with surprisingly elegant results

```js
const first = (x, y) =>
  x

const fibonacci = (n, callback = first) =>
  n === 0
    ? callback (0, 1)
    : fibonacci
        ( n - 1
        , (a, b) => callback (b, a + b)
        )
        
console.log (fibonacci (10)) // 55
// 55 is the 10th fibonacci number
// (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got so tired of seeing that same snippet over and over I wrote this:

```
  var cb = function(g) {
    if (g) {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 
      args.shift(); 
      g.apply(null, args); 
    }
  };
```

I've got hundred of functions doing things like

```
  cb(callback, { error : null }, [0, 3, 5], true);
```

or whatever...

I'm skeptical of the whole "make sure it's function" strategy.  The only legitimate values are a function or falsy.  If someone passes in a non-zero number or a non-empty string, what are you going to do?  How does ignoring the problem solve it?

Comment: The function might be overloaded to either accept some value as the first argument, the function as the first argument or both parameters. There is a use-case to checking whether it's a function. It's also better to ignore the wrong parameter then to throw an error for executing a non-function

Comment: @Raynos -- That's a very, very specific use case.  JavaScript, being weakly typed, isn't good at distinguishing types, and it's usually better to pass in named parameters than trying to distinguish the types and guess what the caller wants: `save( { callback : confirmProfileSaved, priority: "low" })`

Comment: I disagree, there's enough type checking ability. I prefer method overloading, but that's personal preference. This is the kind of thing jQuery does a lot.

Comment: @Raynos -- It's *worse* to ignore the wrong parameter then to throw an error for executing a non-function.  Consider a typical case: the library function is performing some asynchronous activity and the calling function needs to be notified.  So an unsophisticated user, ignoring and failing seem the same: the activity appears to never complete.  However, to a sophisticated user (for example, the original programmer), a failure gives an error message and a stack trace that point directly at the problem; ignore the parameter means tedious analysis to determine what caused "nothing" to happen.

Comment: there's a trade-off to be made though. Throwing an error will crash the run-time, but ignoring it will let other code around it execute as normal.

Comment: @Raynos -- no!  Not execute as "normal", execute in a abnormal, untested fashion.  The calling function wanted you to do *something* with the parameter, you just have no idea what that something is.  Blundering ahead is not a particularly good default.  It's reasoning like yours that gave the world atrocities like PHP and type-coercion and the [catch-ignore antipattern](http://www.rrelos.net/blog/?p=199)!  Remember, if we ignore type errors, the terrorists win!

Answer (score 2):

A valid function is based on the Function prototype, use:

```
if (callback instanceof Function)
```

to be sure the callback is a function

Answer (score 1):

If the criteria for running the callback is that whether its defined or not, then you're fine. Also, I suggest to check if its really a function in addition.

Answer (score 1):

I have sinced moved to coffee-script and found default arguments is a nice way to solve this problem

```
doSomething = (arg1, arg2, callback = ()->)->
    callback()
```

Answer (score 1):

It can easilly be done with [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs):

```
function save (){
  arguments = __({callback: [Function]})
.....do stuff......
  if(arguments.callback){
    callback();
  };
};
```