# Does a matter whether a value is primitive or boxed

Tags: javascript, boxing, typeof

One can use `typeof` to determine whether a value is primitive or boxed.

Consider:

```
typeof "foo"; // "string"
typeof new String("foo"); // "object"
```

In combination with `Object.prototype.toString` we could define the following two functions

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

var is_primitive_string = function(s) {
  return toString.call(s) === "[object String]" && typeof s === "string";
};

var is_boxed_string = function(s) {
  return toString.call(s) === "[object String]" && typeof s === "object";
};
```

Are there **any use cases** for these two functions? (Or similar functions for `Number`, `Boolean`, etc).

The concept behind this question came from the following [Comment by T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792663/javascript-style-optional-callbacks/6792694#6792694).

Should we ever care whether a value we have is primitive or boxed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say there's virtually no point, you almost never care whether you're dealing with a `string` primitive or a `String` object.

There are edge cases. For instance, a `String` object is an actual object, you can add properties to it. This lets you do things like this:

```
function test(arg) {
    arg.foo = "bar";
}
```

If calling code passes in a `string` *primitive*:

```
var s1 = "str";
test(s1);
```

...`arg` gets promoted to a `String` object and gets a property added to it, but that `String` object isn't used by anything after `test` returns.

In contrast, if calling code passes in a `String` *object*:

```
var s2 = new String("str");
test(s2);
```

...then the property is added to that object and the calling code can see it. Consider ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/eceyuh/2)):

```
var s1, s2;

s1 = "str";

display("[Before] typeof s1.foo = " + typeof s1.foo);
test(s1);
display("[After] typeof s1.foo = " + typeof s1.foo);

s2 = new String("str");

display("[Before] typeof s2.foo = " + typeof s2.foo);
test(s2);
display("[After] typeof s2.foo = " + typeof s2.foo);

function test(arg) {
  arg.foo = "bar";
}
```

Output:

```
[Before] typeof s1.foo = undefined
[After] typeof s1.foo = undefined
[Before] typeof s2.foo = undefined
[After] typeof s2.foo = string
```

Note that `s2.foo` is a string, but `s1.foo` isn't (because `s1` was a string *primitive*, the object created when we promoted it in `test` has nothing to do with the calling code).

Is there any use case for this? Dunno. I'd say it would be an extremely edgy edge case if so.

Comment: The fact that boxed values are "passed by reference" compared to primitives can have some interesting consequences.

Comment: @Raynos, what consequences?   Primitives are immutable so there should be no observable difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference for primitives.  I don't think there is any program you could write that could detect whether all `true`s are passed as a reference to an immutable object that resides in a single memory location (as in Rhino) and one where it is a tagged union that is copied as in most other interpreters.

Answer (score 3):

All the `toString` stuff seems to be an attempt to workaround problems with cross-frame mixing of different builtin `String` constructors.  That is unnecessary for checking whether something is a primitive string -- `typeof` is sufficient, so there is no use case for `is_primitive_string`.

I very rarely see arguments passed as `String` instances so I can't see why I would need to check whether something is a `String` instance cross-frame instead of just coercing to a `String` value via `("" + s)` or `String(s)`.  The only time I've ever used a `String` value in production code was when I needed an empty string that was truthy in some [highly optimized code](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/source/browse/trunk/src/json_sans_eval.js#95).

As far as the others go, instances of the `Boolean` class don't behave as one might expect in conditions.

```
if (new Boolean(false)) {
  alert("WTF!");
} else {
  alert("OK");
}

Boolean.prototype.not = function () { return !this; };

if (new Boolean(false).not()) {
  alert("OK");
} else {
  alert("Really, WTF!");
}

if (false.not()) {  // Autoboxing
  alert("OK");
} else {
  alert("Cmon, WTF!");
}
```

`!(false)` is `true`, but when you use create an instance of the `Boolean` class, the `!` operator applies to the object value, and object values are always truthy.

I believe EcmaScript 5 strict mode is changing the way `this` is presented so the last example (`false.not()`) will behave as one might naively expect when `"use strict";` is added to the top of `Boolean.prototype.not` in a valid ES5 interpreter.

With `Number`s, comparisons using `<` are OK and addition and other operators tend to work as expected.  `new Number(0)` and `new Number(NaN)` have the same problems as `new Boolean(false)` around conditions, and of course

```
alert(NaN === NaN);  // false
var NAN = new Number(NaN);
alert(NAN === NAN);  // true
```

and `===` and `!==` compare by reference for all of `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean`.

Comment: Apart from boolean logic and the `!` operator. Is there anything else that acts strangly on boxed vs primitive types. And should we ever check/gaurd against this?

Comment: @Raynos, obviously `new Number(0)` is truthy and `var NAN = new Number(NaN);  alert(NAN === NAN && !!NAN)`.

Answer (score -2):

I use underscore.js methods to detect the type of the variable. Try to use:
isEmpty, isElement, isArray, isArguments, isFunction, isString, isNumber, isBoolean, isDate, isRegExp isNaN, isNull, isUndefined

Described here:
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Comment: We're not talking about type, were talking about checking whether a value is a primitive or boxed type for a particular type (String, Number, Boolean)

Comment: Pardon me. I misunderstood the question.