# Access to Json array with for function

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can i loop throught an  array with the below structure with the function for?

My Array is:

```
        {
            "cod": "200",
            "message": 0.0027,
            "city": {
                "id": 2264456,
                "name": "Portimao",
                "coord": {
                    "lon": -8.53775,
                    "lat": 37.138561
                },
                "country": "PT",
                "population": 0
            },
            "cnt": 1,
            "list": [{
                "dt": 1400328000,
                "temp": {
                    "day": 24.54,
                    "min": 15.3,
                    "max": 24.69,
                    "night": 15.3,
                    "eve": 23.33,
                    "morn": 23.33
                },
                "pressure": 1010.53,
                "humidity": 64,
                "weather": [{
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "sky is clear",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }],
                "speed": 5.17,
                "deg": 150,
                "clouds": 0
            }]
        }
```

My idea is get the array values accessible by doing this:

```
        for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

           data.list[i].temp.max ;
           data.list[i].weather[i]icon
        }
```

The thing is... i´m not getting any information inside weather object... it´s undifined!!! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you'll need two nested for-loops. Also, **note that indices begin at zero, not one**

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    //use: data.list[i].temp.max;
    for (var j=0; j< data.list[i].weather.length; j++){
       //use: data.list[i].weather[j].icon
    }
}
```

---

Easier iterating approach is to use `$.each` or the native `array.forEach`.

Something like:

```
data.list.forEach(function (listItem, index) {
    //use: listItem.temp.max
    listItem.weather.forEach( weatherItem, index) {
        //use: weatherItem.icon
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes i noticed that!! But if you can have a look in my code - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23044665/weather/index.html - i have an array of five days forecast, and i treat the first array element diferently from the other 4... that i i start the for loop from the second to the 5.

Comment: And if i want to generate a div with information from this two objects? For ex. - '<div class="''+ weatherItem.icon +'">Temp Min'+ listItem.temp.max + '</div>'.

Comment: @Legues Yes, that will work. Just fix your quotes. :)

Comment: The forEach case it´s working as i want. I can template the results as i want! :) The thing is, how can i start from the 1 instead of 0 with this function? Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you now how can i disable index 0 from an forEach function, that will be cool, but my problem it´s solved!!! Many thanks!!!! :)

Comment: `if (index == 0) { return; }` do just fine in your case.

Comment: Excelent!!!! It´s working!!!! Hi guys... thanks a lot for those who tried to help me!!!! :) Problem solved!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get like this:

```
$.each(data,function(index,item){
console.log(index+":"+item);
});
```

for accessing list:

```
$.each(data.list,function(index,item){
console.log(item.weather);

})
```

for accessing weather properties:

```
$.each(data.list,function(index,item){
console.log(item.weather);
    $.each(item.weather,function(index1,item1){
    console.log(item1.id);
    console.log(item.icon);
    console.log(item.main);
    })


})
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5wX/3/)

Comment: The can i access by doing this? 
item.list.weather.icon

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check `length` of `data.list.length` instead `data.length` (if you want to traverse `data.list[]` in loop)
2. Array index starts with `0` so, change loop `i=1` to `i=0`

Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.list[i].temp.max);
    console.log(data.list[i].weather[i].icon);
}
```

here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8smXF/)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an object not an array. Sometimes it's useful to think of arrays and objects in a similar way, but sometimes that's just confusing and problematic when you are trying to solve problems (like object traversal in your case) in JavaScript.

You can immediately identify an object when you see curly brakets: {} //this is an object.
You can immediately identify an array when you see square brackets: [] //this is an array.

Your JavaScript, represents an object because it is encapsulated within a {}, even when it contains array [] in some of it's properties.

So what you need is to look over the properties of your objects, and if they are arrays, just loop over with an index from 0 to count - 1. If they are objects, you need to loop their properties.

Example (loop over object properties):

```
for(var prop in {one:1, two:2})
    console.log(prop); //this will print one, then two.
```

Example 2 (loop over array):

```
for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    console.log(array[i]); //outputs whatever is in the array.
```

Now while going through using these loops, you need to decide which one to use next, this is why you need to find out whether an object is an array or not and that's certainly possibly.

One, you can check using instanceof or jQuery.isArray([]); //true. if it's not array then it's a regular object, unless it's a primitive. Check for value is primitive or object: [Does a matter whether a value is primitive or boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793228/does-a-matter-whether-a-value-is-primitive-or-boxed)

**Conslusion**
You need to write your own custom traversal logic, perhaps using some useful libraries like underscore, jQuery or lodash, considering the tools and possibilities.

HTH, Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for your comment and explanation :). My question is what can i do for this situation? - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23044665/weather/index.html - i have an forecast of 5 days but i´m treating the first one diferently of the other ones... but now i see that will be dificult to templating because of the weather object!!! Any suggestions?

Comment: So your problem is that the objects sometimes don't contain the same properties/structure? (I didn't understand what's in your link and the blue/red background is blinding haha)

Comment: Red its the first element on array, and the red area return the other 4 elemnt on array. Red it´s today, and the blue its forecast.

Comment: Decide on the information that you want, and traverse to them? This shouldn't be hard, despite the fact that you are facing difficult JSON structure