# when a function's work is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin, it gets data from an url, fetches, calculates and writes some data in a `div`.

I want to copy this `div` contents to another `div`, when that functions do its work.

for example:

```
$("#div1").myfunction(); // it gets and calculates data and adds to #div1 . it needs 2-3 seconds to be done
var contents = $("#div1").html(); // when myfunction() done, copy contents
$("#div2").html(contents);
```

when i ran that code, i didn't have new contents in `#div2`.

Comment: Does `myfunction` make an Ajax request?

Comment: If `myFunction()` finishes asynchronously, you'll need to use a callback to trigger the copy.

Comment: @karim79: and ajax calls performed by jquery can be *synchronous*. So - nope, it is not that unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to have `myfunction` take a callback parameter which it executes once the request is done

```
function myfunction(cb)
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "page.html",
        success: function(data){
            $("#div1").html(data);
            if(typeof cb === 'function') cb();
        }
    });
}

myfunction(function(){
    $("#div2").html($("#div1").html());
});
```

Comment: You'd also put a check that `cb` is a valid function, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792663/javascript-style-optional-callbacks/6792694#6792694

Comment: assuming you want it to be an optional parameter.

Comment: as long as it is javascript and every parameter is optional by definition - yes, this sort of check would be must-have

Comment: so you're saying that every single parameter to every single function needs to be checked? Either way: added

Comment: If you wish to keep current with your jQuery releases, you should know that `success` will be deprecated in v1.8.

Comment: @ilia choly: as long as you're supposing that `cb` **is a callback** - yes, I think it is a great deal to make sure it really is a callback, to prevent of getting js errors.

Comment: @zerkms `cb` is an unnecessary deep dependency of a callback. If you want to use the jQuery callbacks correctly, the only available callbacks to call `cb` from will be `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()`.

Comment: @rxgx: how is it related to me? :-S

Answer (score 2):

You will simply need to put this line:

```
$("#div2").html($("#div1").html());
```

into the success callback of the ajax code implemented in `myFunction`, to ensure that the operation happens once the client has received the response and inserted it into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax callbacks (such as `success`) will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. Instead, you can use jQuery's `deferred` object to run (or undo) an action that requires one more conditions before it is performed.

```
var successFunction = function() {
  var contents = $("#div1").html();
  var newElement = $("<div id=div2></div>").html(contents);
  $("body").append(newElement);
}

var failedFunction = function() {
  // reset element or undo last change
  window.alert("Update Failed");
}


$.when(
  $.ajax(countParams),
  doCalculate()
).then(
  successFunction(),
  failedFunction()
);
```

[Creating Responsive Applications Using jQuery Deferred and Promises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're the one writing the plugin, you should either hard-code it into the AJAX callback function, or allow for a callback function to be passed in with the options.

If you have no control over the plugin, you'll have to constantly query your `div` to see if it has been updated:

```
var oldHTML = $("#div1").html(),
    counter = 0;

$("#div1").myfunction();

copyHTML();

function copyHTML()
{
    var newHTML = $("#div1").html();

    // we don't want this function to run indefinitely
    if (++counter > 15) return;

    if (newHTML == oldHTML)
        setTimeout(copyHTML, 1000);
    else
        $("#div2").html(newHTML);
}
```

Comment: if a plugin doesn't offer a callback parameter, you have to question it's quality... Also, it's not rocket science to add your own. But how does your code cope with a failed request?

Comment: @ilia choly: Totally right! However, in the absence of anything better, I'd opt for this. I might increase the timeout though (or increase it subsequently upon each call). I added it to the warning though...

Comment: @ilia choly: Added counter to halt execution after x failed attempts.