# What is the JavaScript convention for no operation?

Tags: javascript, function

What is the JavaScript convention for no operation? Like a Python `pass` command.

- One option is simply an empty function: `function() {}`
- jQuery offers `$.noop()`, which simply calls the empty function above.
- Is it acceptable to simply enter a value of `false` or `0`?

In context... all of these work without throwing an error in Chrome:

```
var a = 2;
(a === 1) ? alert(1) : function() {};
(a === 1) ? alert(1) : $.noop();
(a === 1) ? alert(1) : false;
(a === 1) ? alert(1) : 0;
```

EDIT: A lot of people responded with, "don't do this! Change the code structure!" This reminds me of a post where someone asked how to sniff the browser. He received a barrage of posts saying, "DON'T DO THAT! IT'S EVIL," but *nobody told him how to sniff the browser*.  This is not a code review. Imagine that you are dealing with legacy code that can't be changed, and without some function passed in, it will toss an error. Or, simply, that's the way the customer wants it, and *they're paying me*. So, respectfully, please **answer the question**: What is the best way to specify a "no operation" function in JavaScript?

EDIT2: How about one of these?

```
true;
false;
0;
1;
null;
```

Comment: Why not a simple if statement?

Comment: None of those alternatives to `0` are effectively any better (or worse). I'd say the right thing to do is `if (a === 1) doSomething();` and not use `? :` when it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are abusing the ternary operator with a side effect. If you must, do `if (statement) action; else ;`

Comment: Yes `false` or `0` will work; `null` is a nice way to express no-op.

Comment: I hope the ternary has some necessity we can't see for some reason... Very much looks like you complicating your code to feel cool (We've all done it!)

Comment: Just don't specify it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21644803/1636522.

Comment: in your example `$.noop()` should be `$.noop`. the former runs the function and returns undefined.

Comment: `if` should be removed from the language. It encourages people writing ugly code.

Answer (score 130):

To answer the original question, the most elegant and neat implementation of a noop function in pure Javascript (as is also discussed [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/chrislaughlin/noop_no_operation_function/oldest/))  is **Function.prototype**. This is because:

1. Function.prototype is a function:

> `typeof Function.prototype === "function"  // returns true`

2. It can be invoked as a function and essentially does nothing as shown here:

> ```
> setTimeout(function() {
>       console.log('Start: ', Date.now());
>       Function.prototype();
>       console.log('End  : ', Date.now());
>     }, 1000);
> ```

Although this is a "true noop" since most browsers seem to do nothing to execute the noop defined this way (and hence save CPU cycles), there might be some performance issues associated with this (as is also mentioned by others in comments or in other answers).

However, that being said, you can easily define your own noop function and, infact, many libraries and frameworks also provide noop functions. Below are some examples:

```
var noop = function () {};           // Define your own noop in ES3 or ES5
const noop = () => {};               // Define in ES6 as Lambda (arrow function)
setTimeout(noop, 10000);             // Using the predefined noop

setTimeout(function () {} , 10000);  // Using directly in ES3 or ES5
setTimeout(() => {} , 10000);        // Using directly in ES6 as Lambda (arrow function)

setTimeout(angular.noop, 10000);     // Using with AngularJS 1.x
setTimeout(jQuery.noop, 10000);      // Using with jQuery
```

Here is an alphabetical list of various implementations of noop functions (or related discussions or google searches):

[**AngularJS 1.x**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop),  **[Angular 2+](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular%202%20noop%20function)** (Does not seem to have a native
   implementation - use your own as shown above), [**Ember**](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5003),  [**jQuery**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/),  [**Lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#noop),  [**NodeJS**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-noop),  [**Ramda**](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/701),  **[React](https://www.google.com/search?q=react%20noop%20function)** (Does not seem to have a native implementation - use your own as shown above),  [**RxJS**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/util/noop.js.html),
  [**Underscore**](http://underscorejs.org/#noop)

**BOTTOM LINE**: Although Function.prototype is an elegant way of expressing a noop in Javascript, however, there might be some performance issues related to its use. So, you can define and use your own (as shown above)  or use one defined by the library/framework that you might be using in your code.

Comment: This should be the answer. One can even use `Function.prototype()` if you don't need the timeout and want it to execute right away.

Comment: `setTimeout(Function(), 10000);`

Comment: @iegik: +1. Yes, you are correct. All of the following are equivalent: setTimeout(function () {} , 10000); OR setTimeout(new Function(), 10000);OR setTimeout(Function(), 10000); OR setTimeout(Function, 10000);  since the Javascript grammar and the Function constructor implementation allows these constructs.

Comment: In ES6 or using babel or another transpiler `(( )=>{};)` technically Pure JS and much shorter than `function () {}` but exactly equivalent.

Comment: I was interested in finding a no-op-like construct to efficiently turn off debug code in my program. In C/C++, I would have used macros. I tested assigning my fn to Function.prototype and timed it, comparing the results to simply having an if statement inside the function to return immediately. I also compared these to the results of simply removing the function altogether from the loop. Unfortunately, Function.prototype did not perform well at all. calling an empty function was far superior in performance, even faster than calling the function with the simple 'if' test inside to return.

Answer (score 103):

The most concise and performant noop is an **empty arrow function**: `()=>{}`.

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) work natively in all browsers except IE (there is a [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions/) if you must):
[image: MDN]

---

## `()=>{}` vs. `Function.Prototype`

- `()=>{}` is **87% faster** than `Function.prototype` in Chrome 67.
- `()=>{}` is **25% faster** than `Function.prototype` in Firefox 60.
- `()=>{}` is **85% faster** than `Function.prototype` in Edge *(6/15/2018)*.
- `()=>{}` is **65% less code** than `Function.prototype`.

The test below heats up using the arrow function to give bias to `Function.prototype`, yet the arrow function is the clear winner:

```js
const noop = ()=>{};
const noopProto = Function.prototype;

function test (_noop, iterations) {
    const before = performance.now();
    for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) _noop();
    const after = performance.now();
    const elapsed = after - before;
    console.info(`${elapsed.toFixed(4)}MS\t${_noop.toString().replace('\n', '')}\tISNOOP? ${_noop() === undefined}`);
    return elapsed;
}

const iterations = 10000000
console.info(`noop time for ${iterations.toLocaleString()} iterations`)
const timings = {
    noop: test(noop, iterations),
    noopProto: test(noopProto, iterations)
}

const percentFaster = ((timings.noopProto - timings.noop)/timings.noopProto).toLocaleString("en-us", { style: "percent" });
console.info(`()=>{} is ${percentFaster} faster than Function.prototype in the current browser!`)
```

Comment: I created a jsPerf test to compare some options: [noop-function](https://jsperf.com/noop-function). It seems that in Firefox 54, all alternatives seem to be about equivalent; in Chromium 58, `Function.prototype` is drastically slower, but none of the other options have a definite advantage.

Comment: `_=>{}` is one character less and does the same thing.

Comment: @RossAttrill *similar thing - `_=>{}` has a single parameter. If someone is using TypeScript with a reasonably strict config, that would not compile. If you call it, your IDE will likely tell you it accepts a single parameter that can be of any type (both JavaScript and especially TypeScript in vscode).

Comment: The most convenient I could find to make TS & eslint happy was `(() => 5)();` (because they required execution), but, um, never use this in production code. Or tell me why you want to sniff the browser. kk? Thanks.  (My temp use case was to stop eslint from yelling when I commented out debugging `console.log`s, leaving one line in brackets: `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`.` If I add an extra line, it stops complaining. Ok fix while devving. Silly when deploying unless it's transpiled out (which is really should be...).)

Answer (score 13):

whatever you tend to achieve here is wrong. Ternary expressions *shall not* be used as a full statement, only in expression, so the answer to your question is:

none of your suggestions, instead do:

```
var a = 2;
if (a === 1)
    alert(1)
// else do nothing!
```

then the code is easily understandable, readable and as much efficient as it can get.

Why make it more difficult, when it can be simple?

edit:

> So then, does a "no-operation" command basically indicate an inferior code structure?

You're missing my point. All the above is about the ternary expression `x ? y : z`.

But, a no operation command does not makes sense in higher level languages such as Javascript.

It is usually used, in lower level languages such as assembly or C, as a way to make the processor do nothing for one instruction for timing purposes.

In JS, whether you do `0;`, `null;`, `function () {};` or an empty statement, there are great chances that it will be ignored by the interpretor when it is reading it, but *before* it gets interpreted, so in the end, you'll just make your program be loaded more slowly by a really tiny amount of time. *Nota Bene*: I'm assuming this, as I'm not involved in any widely used JS interpreter, and there are chances each interpreter has its own strategy.

In case you use something a bit more complicated, like `$.noop()` or `var foo = function () {}; foo()`, then the interpreter may do an unuseful function call that will end up spoiling a few bytes of your function stack, and a few cycles.

The only reason I see a function such as `$.noop()` would exist, would be to be able to still give a callback function to some event function that would throw an exception if it can't call that callback. But then, it's necessarily a function you need to give, and giving it the `noop` name is a good idea so you're telling your readers (and that may be you in 6 months) that you purposely give an empty function.

In the end, there's no such thing as "inferior" or "superior" code structure. You're either right or wrong in the way you use your tools.. Using a ternary for your example is like using a hammer when you want to screw. It'll work, but you're not sure you can hang something on that screw.

What could be considered either "inferior" or "superior" is the algorithm and ideas you put in your code. But that's another thing.

Comment: So then, does a "no-operation" command basically indicate an inferior code structure?

Comment: @kmiklas: I can't say I've ever found a legitimate need for a NOOP, outside of assembler.

Comment: @zmo: I do understand your point regarding how your comments relate to the ternary expression; everyone seems to have missed my point that this was just an illustrative example of a call to "No Operation" function.

Comment: Of course there are reasons to want/need a no-op feature.  Don't make broad generalizations based on your 12 seconds of deep thought on something.  JavaScript is a language that make functions fully controllable as variables.  Suppose you have a need to disable a function without an explicit test?  This would be perfect for that.  If you have a function that appears frequently, such as a debug statement, it would be nice to be able to switch it off by reassigning the function to no-op rather than having to add extra code to test some variable each time the function appeared.

Comment: @bearvarine thank you for the high opinion you're having of me :-D. You're absolutely right in your comment, but it's not really for code design, just mockup design using a hack. What you describe is also called monkey patching, and there's a reason for that ;-)

Comment: Though, understand that my answer might have been written before the OP edited his answer (I did not verify, but often that's the case when I spliy an answer with an edit). My point was first against using a ternary expression as a statement, then saying there's no such thing as a noop (which is the concept of having the processor skipping an instruction). What you describe is called an empty function, that if it please you you can call noop, like the jquery guys did!

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no problem or performance penalty of using `Function.prototype` over `() => {}`.

The main benefit of `Function.prototype` is having a singleton function rather than re-defining a new anonymous function each time. It's especially important to use a no-op like `Function.prototype` when defining default values and memoizing as it gives you a consistent object pointer which never changes.

The reason I'm recommending `Function.prototype` rather than `Function` is because of they're not the same:

```
Function() === Function()
// false

Function.prototype() === Function.prototype()
// true
```

Also, **benchmarks from other answers are misleading**. In fact, `Function.prototype` performs faster than `() => {}` depending on how you write and run the benchmark:

[You can’t trust JS benchmarks](https://medium.com/cacher-app/how-js-benchmarks-lie-fa35fa989ee0) << Specifically calling out benchmarks on this question.

Don't style your code from benchmarks; do whatever's maintainable and let the interpreter figure out how to optimize in the long run.

Answer (score 8):

I think jQuery `noop()` is mostly intended to prevent code from crashing by providing a default function when the requested one is not available. For example, considering the following code sample, `$.noop` is chosen if `fakeFunction` is not defined, preventing the next call to `fn` from crashing:

```
var fn = fakeFunction || $.noop;
fn() // no crash
```

Then, `noop()` allows to save memory by avoiding to write the same empty function multiple times everywhere in your code. By the way, `$.noop` is a bit shorter than `function(){}` (6 bytes saved per token). So, there is no relationship between your code and the empty function pattern. Use `null`, `false` or `0` if you like, in your case there will be no side effect. Furthermore, it's worth noting that this code...

```
true/false ? alert('boo') : function(){};
```

... is completely useless since you'll never call the function, and this one...

```
true/false ? alert('boo') : $.noop();
```

... is even more useless since you call an empty function, which is exactly the same as...

```
true/false ? alert('boo') : undefined;
```

Let's replace the ternary expression with an `if` statement to see how much it's useless:

```
if (true/false) {
    alert('boo');
} else {
    $.noop(); // returns undefined which goes nowhere
}
```

You could simply write:

```
if (true/false) alert('boo');
```

Or even shorter:

```
true/false && alert('boo');
```

---

To finally answer your question, I guess a "conventional no operation" is the one which is never written.

Comment: However sometimes you have to provide a function. For example with promises then(fn, fn) sometimes you want to provide the second function but not the first function. therefore you need something for a place holder... `mypromise.then($.noop, myErrorhandler);`

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
 (0); // nop
```

To test execution time of this run as:

```
console.time("mark");
(0); // nop
console.timeEnd("mark");
```

result: mark: 0.000ms

Using `Boolean( 10 > 9)` can be reduced it to simply `( 10 > 9)` which returns `true`.  Coming up with the idea to use a single operand I fully expected `(0);` would return `false`, but it simply returns the argument back as can be reviewed by performing this test at the console.

```
> var a = (0);
< undefined
> a
< 0
```

Comment: many who attempt this will get `argument 0 is not a function`

Comment: You're simply assigning 0. IMO `noop` should be a function that evaluates with `undefined` result.

Comment: How is this statement (0); assigning a 0?, where is var and equal sign? There is no function name in front of the (0), so I don't see how this could be an argument?  if you try typeof ( (0) ), it comes back as a number.  When I answer the question, I was providing a statement that I use to mimic a NOP, but I am willing to change my answer to simply use ; to represent an empty statement

Comment: I think (0); is an acceptable solution to OP's question. I think people are getting confused because they found this page while looking for a function that does nothing, rather than a statement that does nothing.The OP isn't helping by initially suggesting `function(){}` as a solution. Calling `(0)()` will cause `TypeError: 0 is not a function`

Comment: I was referring to `var a = (0);`. A no-op shouldn't change memory and your assignment example does just that. The `(0)` on its own may be considered a useless no-op (there are an infinite number of these in JavaScript so there is nothing that makes your example here special).

Comment: @Eggs Where exactly is this useful? And why do you need the parentheses around the zero?

Answer (score 0):

Need a succinct way of conditionally executing an expression, including function calls? *(No noop necessary.)*

```js
true && expression // or `expression()`
```

Need a valid, callable expression with no side effects?

```js
const noop = () => {}
if (true) noop()
```

Need a valid, non-callable expression with no side effects?

```js
void 0;
false;
0;
```