# Javascript function without any code in it

Tags: javascript, function, alert, onbeforeunload

I found the following javascript code snippet as part of a popup window, which is causing my browser to ask if I really want to close the window.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = 'index.html';
        }, 500);
    },5);
    return '';
};
```

I am wondering about these things:

- why would you use a function without any code in it ( code line 3 )
- why do you use window.onbeforeunload inside itself a second time?

Or does this just try to obfuscate its purpose ?

Comment: They are setting `window.onbeforeunload` to a "[no-op](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation)", it's just one way to do it.

Comment: What ^ Jason said. Personally I'd set it to `null` to be more obvious.

Comment: LOL, I think that code was trying to get around the "pop up message", but failed.

Comment: Its from a "Spam Popup", these generally try to annoy you by asking if you really really want to quit the page:-) Thanks for your comments!