# What is the meaning of function(){} in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recently I came across a piece of code which was like this:

```
var noop = function(){};
    options.ondragover = options.ondragover || noop;
    options.ondragleave = options.ondragleave || noop;
    options.ondrop = options.ondrop || noop;
    options.onfilesdone = options.onfilesdone || noop;
```

Comment: It’s just a placeholder function, if any of the `options.*` functions doesn’t exist.

Comment: noop means "no operation". It's an empty function

Comment: In this case just default function to set if we dont have any other in options.

Comment: a simple void function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a No Operation function

Discussed in detail in following link

https://disqus.com/home/discussion/chrislaughlin/noop_no_operation_function/oldest/

[What is the JavaScript convention for no operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation)

Comment: The above shared links are helpful. Thanks for sharing them.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted declared an empty function with the name noop (No Operation) as an alternative to execute when certain conditions apply.
For example the code:

`options.ondragover = options.ondragover || noop;`

checks if `options.ondragover` exists and if not assigns the empty function to the variable.

Answer (score -3):

It is simply a self executed function in which whatever you declare, you can execute the same.

It restrict the scope and make it private and hide the variables from global objects.

```
// Somewhere it is defined as global..
var x = 7;  
// Your piece of code
var x = "roman" // Here, you override the value of x defined earlier.
alert(x); // "roman"    
But when you use a closure which you have mentioned:    
var x = 7;   
// it doesn't affect/change the value of global x   
(function (){ var x = "roman";})();
alert(x); // 7
```

Comment: Self executing function are like this `(function (){ ... })();` not like one described in the question!

Comment: I have explained the way we can use this along with the difference. Is it something wrong in the answer I have described above ?

Comment: I don't think it's that there is anything factually wrong in your answer. It's just that it isn't an answer to this question.