# Instant breakpoint with debugger statement in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm investigating the possibilities to set up a breakpoint instantly when debugging JavaScript

```
for (...) {
  for (...) {
    ...
  }
  // need a breakpoint here
}
```

The problem here is that a breakpoint cannot be toggled on comment line, it needs a statement.

And when `debugger` statement is added to line, another problem appears - it doesn't switch to **Debugger** tab automatically. It just looks like the application is pending, with no indication.

And I'm trying to avoid adding dummy statements because they can be neglected (as for `debugger`, there is at least an inspection rule to highlight it).

Are there any tricks to achieve this? Can `debugger` statement be made to behave like usual breakpoint at least?

Comment: Do you use the JetBrains IDE Support Chrome extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji

Comment: @YannBertrand For client side development. The question is general, it applies to Node, too.

Comment: Could you add a GIF showing the problem with the `debugger` statement?

Comment: @YannBertrand I'm currently unable to do that, but the GIF would be static image - IDE built-in debugger switches to *Debugger* tab when it hits regular breakpoint, but it stays on *Console* tab when it hits `debugger` statement. So it just looks like nothing happens, unless a user switches to  *Debugger* tab manually. Please, let me know if you cannot replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Well yeah it happens sometimes on my PhpStorm with PHP sources (I do my JS debuging inside the Chrome devtools (also possible for Node sources with [`--inspect`](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)). I'm not sure why this happens but this not really a big issue as I usually know that I've got a breakpoint somewhere.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 actually supports Node.js now! So with that you can run Node.js applications through VS 2017 and add break points wherever you please. [Visual Studio 2017 community](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) is also free so it's worth looking into to see if it meets your needs. Note that from my experience this only work well with server application such as Express apps.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to the general question, there is only one answer, and it is the one you do not want to hear:

**You must have a statement for the breakpoint**

There are no tricks that are widely applicable (although there may exist some IDE that allows for convenience breaking immediately after a loop... weird)

Unfortunately, what you want is typically done with a temporary/dummy statements *(exactly the kind that you are trying to avoid)*:

```
for (...) {
  for (...) {
    ...
  }
  // TODO: editors like Eclipse flag TODO lines so they are not lost in the source forest
  setTimeout(Function.prototype, 10000);
}
```

This is due to the mechanics of how (most) debuggers work: basic file and line numbers are stored as debugger information (hints) in the compiled code, and then matched up with the available source during debug execution. For non-compiled languages like JS/PHP, similar techniques are employed with the string that is parsed from source, but lines with comments or brackets are not really executable.

This issue has occasionally reared its ugly head during my own developer journey. It is simply part of the nature of debugging. I hope you can find a coding solution that provides you comfort and some peace of mind.

Comment: Do you have suggestions how to make dummy statement as concise as possible, yet be able to produce error in linter to not accidentally leave it there? `debugger` statement is able to produce an error in linter, yet there's another problem in it. Notice that the question is limited to JS.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a simple [no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation#33458430) statement targeted at JS.

Comment: A noop could be just `0;` but I'm asking for a solution that will report the statement as an error in linter/inspector like it's done for `debugger`, so it would never be left there accidentally. This is what the question addresses, *And I'm trying to avoid adding dummy statements because they can be neglected*.

Comment: Yes, I understand that debugging code being left there accidentally is central. A good IDE will track `TODO`-type comments, but the linter/inspector will probably not. Have you tried something similar to `console.error("need a breakpoint here");` ?