# Double ternary operator that doesn't do anything on one outcome

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I would like my ternary operator to not do anything if the `outcome` is neither 1 nor -1

```
outcome === 1 ? playerScore++ : outcome === -1 ? compScore++ : DO_NOTHING;
```

I realize that I could just write a `0` instead of `DO_NOTHING` but is there a better way to ensure nothing happens if needed?

EDIT: `DO_NOTHING` is just a placeholder for a possible solution to do nothing. Currently I have written `0` instead of it.

Comment: `DO_NOTHING` Is the variable defined? seems like an if else would make so much more sense. Not sure why people think code needs to be one line.

Comment: just put a 0 instead of `DO_NOTHING`. or use an actual `if` like @epascarello said

Comment: beh, use a normal if, and let uglification take care of your code minimisations....

Comment: `''`, `0`, `void(0)`, `undefined` would fit I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...but is there a better way to ensure nothing happens if needed?

Not using the conditional operator, no; you have to have *something* there. `0` is just as good as anything else. Or [as zfrisch notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114161/157247), you could use `&&` instead of a second conditional (see that answer for details).

It's a matter of style, but the "better way" would be to use `if` or `switch` rather than the conditional operator in the first place.

```
if (outcome == 1) {
    playerScore++;
} else if (outcome == -1) {
    compScore++;
}
```

or

```
switch (outcome) {
    case 1:
        playerScore++;
        break;
    case -1:
        compScore++;
        break;
}
```

If you want it condensed for delivery, that's what minifiers/uglifiers/compressors are for. :-)

Comment: Hi! I answered as well. I'm actually quite positive the `&&` operator works here. Unless you can think of a reason that it wouldn't?

Comment: @zfrisch `reason that it wouldn't?`, a better question would be `reason you shouldn't?`  :)

Comment: @zfrisch: Nope, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114161/157247) is good and in keeping with the style in the question. That's the "and" rather than (a second) conditional, but again, very much in keeping.

Answer (score 2):

If you really like to use some short approach, you could use a check and logical AND for incrementing the wanted variable.

```
outcome === 1 && playerScore++;
outcome === -1 && compScore++;
```

Comment: And if you wanted to be really logical, you could use the OR too. -> `outcome === 1 && playerScore++ || outcome === -1 && compScore++ || console.log("nobody won")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested Logical && Operator.

`expr1 && expr2`

if expr1 is true it will run expr2. This means that:

```
outcome === 1 ? playerScore++ : outcome === -1 && compScore++;
```

performs a ternary for outcome, if true it will increase playerScore, if false it will increase compScore only if outcome is equal to -1.

```js
let outcome = 1, playerScore = 0, compScore = 0;
//playScore++
outcome === 1 ? playerScore++ : outcome === -1 && compScore++;

//compScore++
outcome = -1;
outcome === 1 ? playerScore++ : outcome === -1 && compScore++;

console.log(playerScore, compScore);
```

Comment: Don't expect explanations with downvotes, they're **specifically** discouraged. (As are explanations of upvotes.) Despite that: Plus one from me, I think it's horrible on style grounds, but it's absolutely in line with what the OP asked, thus a good answer to the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't realize it was discouraged, and I agree, there's no doubt it's awful stylistically  :)

Comment: It's not so much that commenting a reason for a downvote is  *discouraged* (the opposite is true, in fact; if you have constructive criticism, you *should* share that in a comment) so much as the right to anonymously vote is vigorously defended. It prevents people from going on revenge crusades and voting for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a `noop` function or use one from the frameworks if you use any, like suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation), that way the code is more readable.

a better way to handle this would be `if` statement. since your are not assigning the result of ternary operator to anything. So an `if` statement should suffice. if your goal is to use less space, the you can use any minifiers/uglifiers/compressors as T.J. Crowder suggested.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458430/5268235

```
var noop = function () {};           // Define your own noop in ES3 or ES5
const noop = () => {};               // OR Define your own noop in ES6
setTimeout(noop, 10000);             // Using the predefined noop

setTimeout(function () {} , 10000);  // Using directly in ES3 or ES5
setTimeout(() => {} , 10000);        // Using directly in ES6 as Lambda (arrow function)

setTimeout(angular.noop, 10000);     // Using with angular 1.x
setTimeout(jQuery.noop, 10000);      // Using with jQuery
```

Comment: What purpose would a no-op function serve here? `0` (or `undefined` or `void 0` or `null` or whatever) is just fine.

Comment: to make it more readable I guess, a plain "0 (or undefined or void 0 or null or whatever) " would suggest that the code builds on this logic.