# External React Component need callback function but i dont need it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primefaces

This question is more like a general one but i use my example to express it anyway..

In my webapp i use the primefaces/primereact Overlay Dialog component and there is a required proptype of type function named "onHide". But i dont want to use the function or it should do nothing. What are the options i have if i dont want to use it?

My question basically: Is it okay to make a function with just return or are there better ways?
For example:

```
function onHide() {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation

Comment: It seems like your library isn't made well. Controlled open props should not be coupled with "required" onClose callback. You can wrap this component into a custom one where you give blank function in props. So when you use it somewhere else you don't need to write your blank function again.