# Socket undefined, send don't send if undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, socket.io

Hello I wrote the following function to get someone his socket;

```
var getSocket = function(persId){
    var socketid = users[persId].socket;
    if(io.sockets.connected[socketid]){
        return io.sockets.connected[socketid];
    }
}
```

They are being emitted like so;

```
getSocket(372).emit({ ... });
```

Now if an user has disconnected before the socket is sent out it will result in a undefined socket error, which may cause issues.

is there any way **by modifying the function** (without having to check for `if getSocket(372)`) to make it not throw out an error? it's causing problems right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do instead, is use `socket.io` function, that will check for that already.

`io.to(room).emit()`

On connection just join the user to a room named `372` (I believe that's the user id), and then emit to it:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

    const room = 372; // Get user id somehow
    socket.join(room);

});

// Somewhere
io.to(372).emit(..)
```

---

Answering your specific question, you can return an object with an `emit` [nop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation) method. Also you have to check if the user exist before accessing to `.socket`. You can do that using destructuring.

```
const { socket: socketId } = users[persId] || {};
```

The full function should be:

```
const getSocket = function(persId){
    const { socket: socketId } = users[persId] || {};
    if(socketId && io.sockets.connected[socketId]){
        return io.sockets.connected[socketId];
    }

    return { emit: () => {} }
}
```

And now you don't have to perform a check, since `.emit` will always exist.

```
getSocket(23123213).emit(); // Will no throw if 23123213 doesn't exist
```

Comment: Yeah this I tried before but sockets ended up to the wrong clients and I've tried so many variations, everything would fail to the point io.sockets.emit wouldn't even be working properly anymore. Therefor I'm now using it as it is.

I had the function as; return io.to(persId);

Comment: If it emitted to the wrong client, then you have a bug in your code, where you join users to the wrong channel.

Comment: It was a hundred percent emitting to the right room, and players were in it, I even listed the rooms and it said they existed with their ids, but when I called getSocket sometimes it would work, sometimes it wouldn't and having written like a few thousand lines on the project now its hard to make huge changes to the system.

Comment: It does throw, I set a timeout with a wrong persId, the same issue occurs; TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined

Comment: I think it's an error in my code, because the persId isn't in the object `users` therefor will throw an error.

Comment: It seems to be working, although there is a small error in the code, `const { socket: ... }` should be `const { sockedId: socketId }` I'm guessing, as otherwise it'll throw an error of socketId being undefined, and the other `socketid`'s should be changed to `socketId`

Comment: Your code was trying to access `.socket` property not `.socketId` so... If the property is `.socketId`, `const { socketId } ` will work. But yes about `socketid` changing to `socketId`