# remove array element with remove() is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have used the below code in my API to remove element from an array

```
deleteCommentLike: async(req, res) => {
        const { error } = createComLikeValidation(req.body);

        if (!error) {
            const { user_id, comment_id } = req.body;

            //   const likeModel = new likeSchemaModel({user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id});
            await commentlikeSchemaModel
                .find({ user_id: user_id, comment_id: comment_id })
                .remove();
            let commenttData = await commentSchemaModel.findById(comment_id);
            console.log(commenttData.usersLiked);

            commenttData.likes = --commenttData.likes;
            commenttData.usersLiked.remove(user_id);
            await commenttData.save();

            res.status(200).json({ error: false, data: "done" });
        } else {
            let detail = error.details[0].message;
            res.send({ error: true, data: detail });
        }
    },
```

In here this one line is not working: `commenttData.usersLiked.remove(user_id);`. It doesn't give any error but the `user_id` is not removed from my database.

```
"use strict";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Joi = require('joi');

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //other data
    usersLiked: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        default: []
    }],
    //other data
}
var commentSchemaModel = mongoose.model('comments', commentSchema);
module.exports = {
    commentSchemaModel,
}
```

In my mongodb it looks like below

[image]

I have alredy tried using it as `commenttData.usersLiked.remove(mongoose.Types.ObjectId('user_id'));`
but the result is same.

What can be the reason for this and how could I remove the value from the array ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) operation:

```
commenttData.update({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f099..")}, {$set: {usersLiked: yourUpdatedUsersLikedArray}})
```

The error you expect from remove() is missing as you trigger a js [noop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634886/what-is-the-javascript-convention-for-no-operation) which is just ignored by the compiler.

Mongoose does not implement the attribute update operation the way you use it.

Comment: since there can be more likedusers` yourUpdatedUsersLikedArray` cannot be manually defined I want to remove the given element from the array

Comment: mmm, are you sure about that?