# How to fix "Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported"

Tags: javascript

How to fix the following console errors.

1. `Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported`
2. `InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement`

Because of the above errors, my jobs are not showing in Google search results.

I'm not a developer, so I need suggestions to fix this problem. I will incorporate the necessary changes in my WordPress website.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe these are two unrelated errors. The second one may not be solvable without more information.

Answer (score 189):

### TL;DR

Use `Function.prototype` as a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) callback to quickly get rid of the error message.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=Function.prototype
```

---

### Full Explanation

According to the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params), the `callback` parameter has been required for a very long time. In practice, however, Google has only recently (within the past few days) begun enforcing this requirement.

While it doesn't seem to break anything, it now shows an ugly error message in the console...

> *Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported.*

#### How can I fix it?

The short answer is to specify a `callback` value. Set the name of the JavaScript function that you would like to trigger once the external API library has finished loading.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=FUNCTION_NAME
```

Be warned, **you must specify a real function name!** Otherwise you'll trigger an "is not a function" error message, and simply be trading one error message for another.

#### But I don't have/need a callback function!

If you don't actually *have* a callback function to run immediately after the library loads, you can use `Function.prototype` as a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) stand-in.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=Function.prototype
```

The `Function.prototype` method is native to JavaScript, and does absolutely nothing... It's exactly what you need in a situation like this!

For more information about `Function.prototype`, see [this unrelated SO thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458430/3467557)

Answer (score 6):

I actually created a noop function so I could keep track of when it was called.

```
function gmNoop() { console.log('GMap Callback') }
```

Then added it to my Google map API resource request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='.GOOGLEMAPSKEY.'&callback=gmNoop
```

The reason I needed this was because my application calls initMap() after  other prerequisites. Calling initMap() prior to these other resources would load a map without markers.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this yt video which may help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1asukrHEqMM&ab_channel=KnowledgeBase

It didn't help me much as my problem is slightly different, but gave me an idea of what way to go. Hopefully it helps you. Good luck

::::::::::E D I T::::::::::

Basically what you have to do to get rid of this error is to declare the function (aka initMap) before running the script where you make the API call.

The initMap function is the function where the google map is created and given the characteristics and all that.

initMap function looks like this:

```
function initMap(): void {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
```

The API call is the script line where we put the API-KEY.

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I found two ways to do it, the first way is: have a module that you only have to call before the API with a src script.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="js/scripts.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="js/module/google.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Dentro de google.js es donde guardo mi funcion de initMap()

---

The second way is: write all the code inside a script tag before making the API call.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="js/scripts.js" type="module"></script>
        <script>
            function initMap(): void {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8,
            });
            }
        </script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

> Note that I use **defer** so that the code loads at the bottom of the
> page, this is just my style because I like to declare everything in the
> **head** element.