# Passing anonymous function as callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous-function

Is there a way to pass anonymous function as a custom callback function in Javascript?
I have this code:

```
function notifyme(msg){
    console.log(msg)
}

notifyme("msg", function(){
    //do some custom redirect logic    
});
```

I am trying the above code and it's executing notifyme function, but not going further with redirect code. 
I know I can pass a function name as a callback, but I don't have a specific function that I can pass. This is why they invented the anonymous function I guess.

It'd be really nice if there was a way to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Style : optional callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792663/javascript-style-optional-callbacks)

Comment: The question is not about optional callback, it's about passing anonymous function call back

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code pattern should be like

```js
function notifyme(msg,callback){
    console.log(msg);
    // Do your stuff here
    if(callback){
      callback();
    }
}

notifyme("msg", function(){
    //do some custom redirect logic    
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call your function simply by invoking it `()`:

```js
function notifyme(msg, myFunc){
        console.log(msg);
        myFunc();
}
    
notifyme("msg", () => {
        console.log("function called");   
});
```

`myFunc` in the above is a variable pointing at your function. By invoking it, `()` you call the function that the variable (`myFunc`) points at.

This answer doesn't go into details about the *custom redirect logic*. Because I don't know what this does.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your callback!

```
function notifyme(msg, callback){
    console.log(msg);
    callback();
}

notifyme("msg", function(){
//do some custom redirect logic    
});
```