# How to set a callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I want to excecute function b after the setTimeout function a has finished. I allready know i need a asynchronous callback function for that but have problems to realise that.

```
setTimeout(function a (){
   element.classList.add('classNameA');
},200);

function b () {
   element.classList.add('classNameB');
}
```

I tried this one but it doesn't work, what is wrong with that?

```
setTimeout(function a (b){
   element.classList.add('classNameA');
},200);

function b () {
   element.classList.add('classNameB');
}
```

EDIT: The function a setTimeout is needed because of an previous transition duration. Function b should get excecuted immediately after function a has done its work.

EDIT: i made my example more clear - i have two different classes i have to add.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42203607/4693938

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will in fact call your function after the timeout. Just call your function `a()` instantaneously and pass `b` to `setTimeout`.

Example:

```
 function a (){
   element.classList.add('className');
 }

 function b () {
   element.classList.remove('className');
 }

 setTimeout(async function (){
   await a();
   b();
 },200); // a is called after 200 milliseconds
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your sample, but it doesn't work for me. The function a has a timeout because of an transition, after which the function have to get excecuted. The problem is, that i want function b excecuted immediately after the function a is done, without an additional setTimeout function.

Comment: Got it! Hope you are trying to call both `a` and `b` one after one, after specified time without additional timeout?

Comment: correct! But i think in your sample a and b would be excecuted synchronous, or not?

Comment: Yes, first `a` will be called then `b`

Comment: Okay, but i need it asynchronous, in youre example both would be excecuted simultaneously, but i need b after a is done.

Comment: Edited my answer for your use-case, now function `b` waits untill `a` is completely executed.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
function b() {
   element.classList.remove('className');
}

setTimeout(function a(){
   element.classList.add('className');
   b();
},200);
```

Or do you need something like this:

```
setTimeout(function a(){
   element.classList.add('className');
   setTimeout(function b() {
       element.classList.remove('className');
   }, 200);
},200);
```

Comment: Wouldn't sample b excecute function b synchronous? I need it to get started after function a is done and i don't want a second setTimeout function for that.

Comment: I don't really get what do you want to do. Yeah the first block will execute function b() synchronously after the function a(). I think you should try with promise, look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Okay i will take a look on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 function a (){
   element.classList.add('className');
   setTimeout(b,200);
 }

 function b () {
   element.classList.remove('className');
 }

 a();
```

This calls function a and 200 milliseconds later calls function b

Comment: Thanks for your sample, but it doesn't fit to my situation. I edited my Question.

Comment: Function a() happens immediately and the animation would happen for 200ms right?

Comment: Yep, you're right, but function a has to wait for the animation duration of 200ms and function b should excecuted immediately after this.

Comment: In the above, function a gets  executed and  className exists for 200ms after which it is removed.

Comment: Ah okay now i understand why my Question is confusing - i have to different classes, it's not the same that gets added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript Promises to execute function `b` once function `a` done executing.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
function a() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout((function() {
   console.log('class added');
   resolve(element.classList.add('red')); 
    }), 2000);
});
}
function b() {
  console.log('class removed..'); 
     element.classList.remove('red');
}
a().then(b);
```

```css
.red{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>SetTimeout</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="element">hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```